# Dropzone JS only uploading one file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am using DropzoneJS in one of my projects. I am using laravel to process the backend for file upload. I used a div in my form and add the dropzone class to it.

```
<div class="col-md-12 dropzone file_upload"></div>
```

it works fine but only one file is being uploaded. I want it to upload multiple files simultaneously.

I already set the `parallelUploads` option in my dropzone configuration to `10` and the `maxFiles` option to `10` also.

here is my code for the dropzone configuration:

```
$("div.file_upload").dropzone({
    url: upload,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    autoProcessQueue: true,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    params: {
      "model_id": 1,
      "user_id" : 2
    },
    maxFiles: 10,
    parallelUploads: 10,


});
```

below is my code for the backend

**Controller.php**

```
public function uploadPhoto(Request $request){

    foreach ($request->file('file') as $file) {

        $filename = uniqid().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move('images/booking', $filename);

        //save details to db
        $photo= new InspectionPhotos();
        $photo->inspection_id = $request['inspection_id'];
        $photo->product_id = $request['product_id'];
        $photo->photo_path = $filename;
        if($photo->save()){
            return response()->json([
            'message' => 'OK'
            ]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple attribute set on the input, like so? <input name="file" type="file" multiple />

Comment: @Vivek yes, I set the multiple attribue value to true..

Comment: If you have the option uploadMultiple set to true, then Dropzone will append [] to the name. So you need to add this parameter in your js script `paramName: "file[]",`.

Comment: I think the problem is the return statement in Controller.php. After the first file is saved, the uploadPhoto() function returns, never getting to the second file. Use try-catch to handle exceptions and move the return out of foreach loop. Hope this helps

Comment: @Vivek thanks!! that solved my problem. I removed the return statement and all files got uploaded.. thanks man,, I've been fixing this for half a day now. can you add it as an answer so I can accept it.. thanks again..

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the return statement in `Controller.php`.

After the first file is saved, the function uploadPhoto() returns, never getting to save the second file.

Wrap the `save()` function in `try-catch` and return error status in the catch block, and handle the errors in front-end appropriately. You might also want to have `$file->move()` in `try-catch` as it might throw errors as well.

Finally, move the `return` statement out of `foreach` to return success status.

Glad the answer helped you, cheers!